# In-app Notification

Tags: android, notifications

When the application launch it retrieves data from a database. If there is new data, I want that the application displays a in-app notification (banner) to warn the user.

For the moment I implemented this:

```
if (!taskToNotify.isEmpty()) {
            //Notification builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event_notification);
            builder.setContentTitle(taskToNotify.get(0).getName() + mContext.getString(R.string.notification_content_task));
            builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

            // inbox style
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            inboxStyle.addLine(mContext.getString(R.string.notification_detail_date) + taskToNotify.get(0).dueDateToString());
            inboxStyle.addLine(mContext.getString(R.string.notification_detail_location) + taskToNotify.get(0).getLocationName());

            // Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
            builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);


            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            builder.build();
        }
```

But this doesn't work for the moment. No notification is displayed when the code runs.

Is there a possibility to do that on an Android phone? Or I should another manner to display this information to the user?

Thank you for your precious help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `setContentText()` otherwise it does not satisfy the requirements.

> When creating a notification, specify the UI content and actions with a NotificationCompat.Builder object. At bare minimum, a Builder object must include the following:

- A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
- A title, set by setContentTitle()
- Detail text, set by setContentText()

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html